# Run a .NET .dll file with PHP exec()

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, centos, exec

I have an **start.sh** file that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd /var/server
dotnet /var/server/Asp.Sync.Service.dll &
```

I want to make a script that will start this service using exec().

However when I run:

```
$exec = exec('dotnet /var/server/Asp.Sync.Service.dll &', $output, $return);
```

I get an error that the service couldn't start.

While when I try:

```
$exec = exec('/var/server/start.sh &', $output, $return);
```

I get no output whatsoever, even though the service was started successfully. And when I click Control+C it shuts off the entire service.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the script work without `cd /var/server`? Also what output do you except if you run the command asynchronously? Check out `nohup` too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to without `cd /var/server`. Now sure how could I combine that and the other command in `exec` as one line. @IllidanS4

Comment: @IllidanS4 Am expecting a response that it was successful, returns a few lines when I start from terminal.

Comment: It could be combined like `cd /var/server && dotnet Asp.Sync.Service.dll &`, but PHP might stop reading the output too early since it's asynchronous. In this case, `popen` may help.

Comment: @IllidanS4 So `popen("cd /var/server && dotnet Asp.Sync.Service.dll &","r")`?

Comment: Without the `&` in this case, since it will be started asynchronously anyway. Use to returned handle for `fread`/`fgets` etc. then to get the output. However, if the service would live longer than the httpd process, it may be closed forcibly when httpd is restarted. Check out `nohup` to fix it.